# Exception : Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::serialize() must return a string or NULL

Tags: authentication, symfony, mapping

I am not able to authenticate in symfony2 with the 'Employee' entity as it contains many mapping with other entities in my project. some of my mapping is as follows:

```
/**
 * @var EmployeeDesignation
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EmployeeDesignation")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_designation_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $employeeDesignation;

/**
 * @var EmployeeDesignation
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EmployeeType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $employeeType;
```

Authentication works fine without any mapping. I have tried with 'Serialize()' and 'Unserialize()' methods in it like below:

```
class Employee implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {
    /**
     * serialize the username
     * @return serialize
     */
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize($this->emailOfficial);
    }

    /**
     * unserialize
     * @param $data
     */
    public function unserialize($data) {
        $this->em = unserialize($data);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error after doing the above method:

```
You cannot refresh a user from the EntityUserProvider that does not contain an identifier. The user object has to be serialized with its own identifier mapped by Doctrine.
```

I have tried this way so as to get rid of the previous error, which is as follows:

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::serialize() must return a string or NULL
```

So, can anybody please suggest a way to overcome from this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have encountered something similar, and after some research, I tried the same things as you did.

But at some point, I found out that by setting the `__sleep` method, every thing worked fine.

```
class User implements PlayerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
...

    public function __sleep()
    {
        return array('id');
    }
...
```

- Make sure that the field which is defined as `@ORM\Id` is part of the returned array.
- Make sure to drop the browser cookie, since it uses the session.

I don't know exactly why it causes this when setting up a new association (mine was a ManyToMany), but It probably originate from this place:

```
// see Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse()
...
        $event->getRequest()
            ->getSession()
            ->set('_security_'.$this->contextKey, serialize($token));
...
```

Hope this could help someone.

**Edit:**

References:

- http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=35764
- http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=es&u=http://jonsegador.com/2012/03/error-con-symfony2-you-cannot-refresh-a-user-from-the-entityuserprovider-that-does-not-contain-an-identifier/

Comment: I think this error message appears when your user entity has a relation that links back to user, ex.: `User->Article->Author` (`User` has many `Articles` and `Article` has `User` as author) then serialization fails. Thats why when you serialize `User` using only primary key (id) all things done right. So, use `__sleep` function and return primary key there.

Answer (score 2):

For me only this worked:

`class User implements UserInterface`

to

`class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable`

and I needed to add following methods to `User` class:

```
public function serialize() {
    return serialize($this->username);
}

public function unserialize($data) {
    $this->username = unserialize($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another possibility to solve this issue. You have to make the visibility of all properties of the entities which are associated with your user to 'protected'

See: http://www.metod.si/symfony2-error-usernamepasswordtokenserialize-must-return-a-string-or-null/

Answer (score 0):

You should put "protected" in every variable of your user class. At least for me that work :)